# How to connect to keysight n9020a remotely?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, analyzer, spectrum

How to connect to keysight n9020a remotely via ethernet so that I send commands and receive measured values in response?

Someone may have already tried to do this? All the solutions from the official website did not lead to a solution, I'm already thinking of just connecting via Microsoft Remote Desktop